# Javascript, In Google add-on, I try to get all folders and subfolders in specific folder

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-drive-api, directory

I am a student in stage and I bug on that problem. I was trying multiple solution without success in a add-on for spreadsheet, exemple :

```
var childFolders = DriveApp.getFolderById('ID').getFolders();
```

or

```
var childFolders = DriveApp.getFolderById('ID').searchFolders("mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'");
```

I get only the folders in but not the subfolders of them.

It's strange when you can have all folders of your drive with this command :

```
var childFolders = DriveApp.getFolders();
```

I want the folder and all subfolder. Detail I will have to use a trigger because I exceed the time limit of 6 min, over 7000 folders in drive. Exemple : One folder at the root can have a tree folders of 500 folders.

I try to avoid a recursive function for that. Combine recursively and trigger is ... ! My script must get a folder and all of is subfolders.
I get the key of the first folder to start.

Well if you have an idea, you are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I'll just give you something to start with just to show that I'm able to get the subfolders inside a folder, starting from the root.

```
root > mainFolder > subFolder (the tree can go on)
```

I used [Class Folder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#getFiles()) and 
[Class FolderIterator](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder-iterator) as reference.

```
function getSubFolders() {

  var folderArray=[];
  //displays all the folders assigns it to 'rootFolder' variable
  var rootFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('root').getFolders();
  //iterate over the root folders
  while (rootFolder.hasNext()) {

    var mainFolder = rootFolder.next();
    //assign the IDs of the root folders to an array
    folderArray.push(mainFolder.getId());
    Logger.log(mainFolder.getName());
  }
    //go inside one of the folders of your choice using the ID inside the array so we can use it to access the sub-folders
    var newFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderArray[4]).getFolders();
  //loop over the sub-folders inside if it has any
  while (newFolder.hasNext()) {
   //I had sub-folders inside so I accessed it and displayed their names
    var subFolders = newFolder.next();
    Logger.log(subFolders.getName());
  }

}
```

And sure enough I got the subFolders

```
[17-04-14 15:28:45:256 HKT] Subfolder3
[17-04-14 15:28:45:257 HKT] Subfolder2
[17-04-14 15:28:45:259 HKT] Subfolder1
```

Comment: Thanks, I will split my research in one sheet for each folder. I like the way to get the root. It's so simple, I was getting the ID of the drive. It's 
also works, but your way is better.